# Not able to access MSSQLSERVER-MIB using SNMP Protocol

Tags: networking, snmp, snmp4j

I was trying to access MSSQLSERVER-MIB on Windows Server 2012 using SnmpWalk.exe . The object that I am particularly interested is the **mssqlSrvState**, whose oid is: 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.1.4.1.1.1.1.5 . Although the MS SQL Service is running on the server, I was unable to obtain information about any of the objects in MSSQLSERVER-MIB. Does this mean that SnmpWalk is unaware of MSSQLSERVER's MIB list? As an alternative, I used SNMP4J Java API and SnmpGet.exe from snmpsoft.com, but they failed as well. The show the error "Failed to get value of SNMP variable. Variable does not exist >." Please suggests ways to access MSSQLSERVER's MIB. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an old article says, SNMP support has been removed since MSSQL 2005.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179428(v=SQL.90).aspx

Comment: Monitoring the MS SQl service was one of my vital objectives. Guess I'll have to work with a different protocol. I have read a little about WMI protocol. I will have to look into it further. Which protocol/methodology would you suggest to accomplish my task?